# D3 - To add Data Labels to a simple bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know this is easy and I saw some examples in this forum as well as other websites as well, but I simple can't figure it out.

I'm new in using D3 library to generate the charts. I'm trying to learn by creating bar chart.

My question is how to add the Data Labels into the chart?

Below is the codes I have.

then I have my JS:

```
    var chartwidth = 800;
    var chartheight = 600;

    var data =  [
      {"Start_Dt":"Jan 15","UnitName":"Unit 1","ProgramName":"ProgramName 1","AttendCnt":159,"NewcomerCnt":10}
      , {"Start_Dt":"Jan 22","UnitName":"Unit 2","ProgramName":"ProgramName 2","AttendCnt":178,"NewcomerCnt":5}
      , {"Start_Dt":"Feb 14","UnitName":"Unit 2","ProgramName":"ProgramName 3","AttendCnt":240,"NewcomerCnt":46}
      , {"Start_Dt":"Feb 19","UnitName":"Unit 1","ProgramName":"ProgramName 4","AttendCnt":201,"NewcomerCnt":10}
      , {"Start_Dt":"Feb 26","UnitName":"Unit 2","ProgramName":"ProgramName 5","AttendCnt":177,"NewcomerCnt":7}
      , {"Start_Dt":"Mar 12","UnitName":"Unit N","ProgramName":"ProgramName N","AttendCnt":184,"NewcomerCnt":3}
    ];                          

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 300, left: 40},
        width = chartwidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = chartheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");
    var formatTime = d3.time.format("%e %B");

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var x2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeBands([0, width], 0);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom"); 

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.AttendCnt = +d.AttendCnt;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Start_Dt + " " + d.ProgramName; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.AttendCnt; })]);

    //Create X Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)                        
      .selectAll("text")  
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" )
      .append("text")
      .attr("y", 25)
      .attr("x",x.rangeBand()/2 )
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "20px")
      .style("color", "black")
      .text(function(d,i) { return "xxx"; }); 

    //Create Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Attendance");

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)                                 
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Start_Dt + " " + d.ProgramName); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.AttendCnt); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.AttendCnt); });
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf3fP.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyVno.jpg)

How to modify the codes to get the result I wanted? Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i haven't tested the code but it could be something like this :

```
svg.selectAll(".barText")
      .data(data)                                 
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "barText")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Start_Dt + " " + d.ProgramName); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return height - y(d.AttendCnt); })
      .text(function(d) { return d.AttendCnt; })
      ;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I modified the codes a bit and it apparently worked for me!

Tks for your help!! I had been struggled for last 2 days just to solve this issue.

Comment: great! Don't forget to update your post with your anwser, it can help someone else ;)

Comment: Actually I'm first time using stackoverflow to post a question. Do we have a concept of "closing" this question? or I should close it by clicking "Answer Your Question"?

Comment: If my anwser didn't help you, do not mark awser as "resolved" but just awser your own question by posting your anwser and mark it to resolved

Comment: @Trowa did you get a solution? could you post it? I am in a similar predicament and am having trouble positioning the text.